# Vim highlight a word with * without moving cursor

Tags: vim, highlight, text-cursor

I would like to be able to highlight the word under cursor without going to the next result.

The solution I found uses a marker:

```
noremap * mP*N`P
```

Is there any better solution ?

I noticed vim is not really good to keep the position of its cursor after the execution of commands. For instance, when I switch buffer, the cursor go back to the begining of the line.

I might be interesting to have a global setting for this.

Comment: This wiki page has a section on this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's unfortunately no global setting for that.

One common solution to the "highlight without moving" problem is:

```
nnoremap * *``
```

One solution to the "keep the cursor position when switching buffers" problem is:

```
augroup CursorPosition
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufLeave * let b:winview = winsaveview()
  autocmd BufEnter * if(exists('b:winview')) | call winrestview(b:winview) | endif
augroup END
```

Answer (score 8):

As detailed [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches#Highlight_matches_without_moving), you can define a map as follows:

`:nnoremap <F8> :let @/='\<<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>\>'<CR>:set hls<CR>`

Comment: If you want to use asterisk instead of F8:

`nnoremap * :let @/ = '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'\|set hlsearch<C-M>`

Answer (score 3):

My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) changes the `*` command, so that it doesn't jump to the next match; you can still jump by supplying a `[count]`. It also extends that command to visual mode (another frequently requested feature not in Vim), and some more.

Comment: No bundle/vundle github repository for your plugin ?